# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRenderingOpenGL

Tags: ros, catkin, apriltags

```
            Errors     << apriltag_ros:make /home/ravinspect/catkin_ws/logs/apriltag_ros/build.make.001.log                                                                                                            
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRenderingOpenGL
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkImagingHybrid
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkIOImage
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkCommonTransforms
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkCommonExecutionModel
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkDICOMParser
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkIOCore
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkImagingColor
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRenderingContext2D
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRenderingGL2PS
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRenderingContextOpenGL
            /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lvtkRenderingLabel
            collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
            make[2]: *** 
           
       
[/home/ravinspect/catkin_ws/devel/.private/apriltag_ros/lib/libapriltag_ros_common.so] 
       Error 1
              make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/apriltag_ros_common.dir/all] Error 2
```

I want to build a workspace with `catkin build` but i am taking this error while building workspace. I tried bunch of solutions but still i am taking this error.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First install

```
sudo apt install libvtk5-dev
```

and then remove opencv and reinstall will solve the issue

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had 3 OpenCV versions, and this situation caused this error. I deleted all of them and install OpenCV-4.5.1. Now I am able to create my workspace without any problem.